# Adding stack info to logging format in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, io

Is there a way to use variable data in the actual format part of the logger?

I want my logs to contain the names of the functions on the stack. For example here is the following code:

```
# logging_utils.py

def init_logger(logger_name: str) -> logging.Logger:

    log = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
    log.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    formatter = logging.Formatter(f'[ %(asctime)s ] [ %(levelname)s ] [ %(callStack?)s ] %(message)s')

    handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    log.addHandler(handler)

    return log


def format_stack() -> str:
    return ':'.join(frame.function for frame in inspect.stack()[::-1][:-1]).replace('<module>:', '')



def f():
    g()

def g():
    h()

def h():
    logger = init_logger('x')
    logger.info('My actual message')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    f()
```

I would like the logging messages to look like

```
[ 2019-02-18 14:14:23,558 ] [ INFO ] [ logging_utils:f:g:h ] My actual message
```

The nearest I came to this is using a custom class like this:

```
import sys
import inspect
import logging


class Logger:

    _logger: logging.Logger

    def __init__(self, name: str):

        logger = logging.getLogger(name)
        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

        handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
        handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

        formatter = logging.Formatter(f'[ %(asctime)s ] [ %(levelname)s ] %(message)s')

        handler.setFormatter(formatter)

        logger.addHandler(handler)

        self._logger = logger

    @staticmethod
    def _format_stack_for_logger() -> str:

        stack = inspect.stack()[::-1]
        stack_names = (inspect.getmodulename(stack[0].filename),
                       *(frame.function
                         for frame
                         in stack[1:-3]))

        return '::'.join(stack_names)

    def _log(self, level: int, msg: str, *args, **kwargs):
        self._logger.log(level, '[ %s ] %s', self._format_stack_for_logger(), msg, *args, **kwargs)

    def debug(self, msg: str, *args, **kwargs):
        self._log(logging.DEBUG, msg, *args, **kwargs)

    def info(self, msg: str, *args, **kwargs):
        self._log(logging.INFO, msg, *args, **kwargs)

    def warning(self, msg: str, *args, **kwargs):
        self.info(logging.WARNING, msg, *args, **kwargs)

    def error(self, msg: str, *args, **kwargs):
        self._log(logging.ERROR, msg, *args, **kwargs)

    def critical(self, msg: str, *args, **kwargs):
        self._log(logging.CRITICAL, msg, *args, **kwargs)


def f():
    g()


def g():
    h()


def h():
    logger = Logger('x')
    logger.info('My actual message :(')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    f()
```

But the stack trace information is... semi-hard-coded(?) into the logging string. I am looking for an elegant way to obtain this outcome.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Thanks to @VinaySajip fot the nudge in the correct direction.

Unfortunately the default `Formatter`'s `format` method just appends the output of `formatStack` at the end of the string to be printed. No matter what you do, as long as you use the default `format` implementation that is what will happen.

What I did was to extend the `Formatter` class, reimplementing the `format` method. The contents of the format method are 70% copy and pasted from the `logging` module but the part that appends the stack info is removed.

Instead, the nicely formatted result of `inspect.stack()` (returned by the new `formatStack`) is placed  in the `stack_info` member of the `LogRecord` that will be formatted.

This is done because to get the final message that will be printed, the dictionary of `LogRecord` is used as the second operand of `fmt_string % args`. So when the format string is interpolated with the dictionary of `LogRecord`, `LogRecord.stack_info` will contain the nicely formatted call stack so all one really has to do is use `%(stack_info)s` in their format string.

Essentially I have added support for `%(stack_info)s` in the format string of the formatter.

The code:

```
import sys
import inspect
import logging

from logging import Logger


class CallStackFormatter(logging.Formatter):

    def formatStack(self, _ = None) -> str:
        stack = inspect.stack()[::-1]
        stack_names = (inspect.getmodulename(stack[0].filename),
                       *(frame.function
                         for frame
                         in stack[1:-9]))
        return '::'.join(stack_names)

    def format(self, record):
        record.message = record.getMessage()
        record.stack_info = self.formatStack()
        if self.usesTime():
            record.asctime = self.formatTime(record, self.datefmt)
        s = self.formatMessage(record)
        if record.exc_info:
            # Cache the traceback text to avoid converting it multiple times
            # (it's constant anyway)
            if not record.exc_text:
                record.exc_text = self.formatException(record.exc_info)
        if record.exc_text:
            if s[-1:] != "\n":
                s = s + "\n"
            s = s + record.exc_text
        return s


def get_logger(name: str, fmt: str = '[ %(asctime)s ] [ %(levelname)-5s ] [ %(stack_info)s ] %(message)s') -> Logger:

        logger = logging.getLogger(name)
        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

        handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
        handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

        formatter = CallStackFormatter(fmt)

        handler.setFormatter(formatter)

        logger.addHandler(handler)

        return logger
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to have a custom `Formatter` subclass which overrides the `formatStack` method, which is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html?highlight=formatstack#logging.Formatter.formatStack).

> Formats the specified stack information (a string as returned by `traceback.print_stack()`, but with the last newline removed) as a string. This default implementation just returns the input value.

Comment: Thank you! I have solved my problem! The way you described did not offer the possibility of doing so directly however it did lead to another interesting implementation that does exactly what I wanted! Please, have a look!

Answer (score -1):

I can't comment, so I am using an answer :

Here's a decorator I used to use, which logs the executed function, with its args

```py
def logging(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        import logging
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        time = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
        logging.basicConfig(filename='logs/webservices.log', level=logging.INFO)
        handle = f(*args, **kwargs)
        logging.info(f'[{time}] - Executing instruction : [{" ".join((inspect.stack()[1][4][0]).split())}]')
        logging.info(f'[{time}] - with args [{args}]')
        logging.info(f'[{time}] - Returned result [{handle}]')
        return handle


    return wrapper
```

Comment: Thanks! But that is not what I wish to do at all! I need the logging function to be callable, not for a decorator to log function calls. (i.e. I want ot have multiple logs/"prints" in the same function, and i want to know what function that is, who called that function, who called the calling function and so on)